# How to get last n characters from a form request field in wiremock response template?

Tags: wiremock

I have a wiremock stub like below

```
{
   "id":"86c2bb75-6de5-48aa-9c14-3cfc2483d12b",
   "name":"v1_payment_methods",
   "request":{
      "url":"/stripe/v1/payment_methods",
      "method":"POST",
      "bodyPatterns":[
         {
            "equalTo":"type=card&card[cvc]=890&card[number]=4242424242424242&card[exp_month]=1&card[exp_year]=2043",
            "caseInsensitive":false
         }
      ]
   },
   "response":{
      "status":200,
      "body":"{\n  \"id\": \"pm_{{randomValue length=24 type='ALPHANUMERIC'}}\",\n  \"object\": \"payment_method\",\n  \"billing_details\": {\n    \"address\": {\n      \"city\": null,\n      \"country\": null,\n      \"line1\": null,\n      \"line2\": null,\n      \"postal_code\": null,\n      \"state\": null\n    },\n    \"email\": null,\n    \"name\": null,\n    \"phone\": null\n  },\n  \"card\": {\n    \"brand\": \"visa\",\n    \"checks\": {\n      \"address_line1_check\": null,\n      \"address_postal_code_check\": null,\n      \"cvc_check\": \"unchecked\"\n    },\n    \"country\": \"US\",\n    \"exp_month\": {{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{lookup form 'card[exp_month]'}},\n    \"exp_year\": {{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{lookup form 'card[exp_year]'}},\n    \"fingerprint\": \"{{randomValue length=16 type='ALPHANUMERIC'}}\",\n    \"funding\": \"credit\",\n    \"generated_from\": null,\n    {\"last4\": \"4242\",\n    \"networks\": {\n      \"available\": [\n        \"visa\"\n      ],\n      \"preferred\": null\n    },\n    \"three_d_secure_usage\": {\n      \"supported\": true\n    },\n    \"wallet\": null\n  },\n  \"created\": {{now format='unix'}},\n  \"customer\": null,\n  \"livemode\": false,\n  \"metadata\": {},\n  \"type\": \"{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{form.type}}\"\n}",
      "transformers":[
         "response-template"
      ]
   },
   "uuid":"86c2bb75-6de5-48aa-9c14-3cfc2483d12b",
   "persistent":true,
   "insertionIndex":7
}
```

In the response body `last4` I want to get the last 4 characters from `card[number]` field in `request body`. Can someone let me know how can I do this?

Wiremock version

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.35.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use `regexExtract`

```
{{#assign 'last4'}}{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{lookup form 'card[number]'}}{{/assign}}\"last4\": \"{{regexExtract last4 '.{4}$'}}\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `substring` function from Handlebars, you can nest your `last4` response as follows:

```
...\"last4\": "\{{formData request.body 'form' urlDecode=true}}{{substring (lookup form 'card[number]') 12}}\"...
```

`substring` is a handlebars string helper function to find a string within a string, starting at the index of the character in a given string (in this case, the 13th character), going until the index of the second number, if given (otherwise, such as this case, going until the end of the string.)

Combining that with the `lookup` function, by nesting it with parenthesis, provides the value that the `substring` function uses for lookup.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the starting number based on string length? For example, for 16 character I have to start at 12, for 17 character I have to start at 13.